# JavaFX webview. How to detect when window.print() is called

Tags: printing, webview, javafx, handler

In JavaFX WebEngine you can set a prompt handler, a confirm handler and an alert handler.
You can also add a changeListener to a worker state.

However, I want to get notified, when window.print() is called. Since javaFX WebView doesn't support printing in Java7, I would then like to implement my own printing logic.

At the moment I can only print using window.mymember.print(), since I used JSOBject.setMember() to register my own member. It would be nicer if the user could just call the normal window.print() method.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out, that you can actually override the window.print() method in javascript. So I override it to call mymember.print().
I execute this  before I register my member:

```
 this._webBrowser.getEngine().executeScript("window.print = function () {window.mymember.print();};");
```